# Require not working the way I thought it would

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, browserify, babeljs

So I have the following gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require("babelify");


gulp.task('make:flare-currency', function() {
  return browserify({entries: [
        'src/add-new-currency/flare-currency.js',
        'src/add-new-currency/currencies/set_up_currencies.js'
      ]})
      .transform(babelify)
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source('Flare-Currency.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/flare/currency/'));
});
```

I have the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "flare-collection",
  "description": "collection of scripts for the RPG Maker MV system.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.0",
    "browserify": "11.2.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "1.1.0",
    "babelify": "6.4.0",
    "underscore.string": "2.3.0"
  }
}
```

When I try to do, inside: `src/add_new_currencies/flare_currency.js`

```
 var UnderScoreString = require('underscore.string/string');
```

I get:

> Error: Cannot find module 'underscore.string/string' from
>   '/Users/AdamBalan/Documents/Flare-Collection/src/add_new_currencies'

All of my require statements require that I do: `var bla = require('some/file/to/include.js')`

All of my classes (I am using es6) have, at the bottom of the file: `module.exports = ClassName;`

**Why am I getting this error?**

More importantly, **why do I have to include the path to the js file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`underscore.string` don't have a `string` submodule (function). If You want load all packages try `_s = require('underscore.string')`. If You want load single module like `slugify` try `slugify = require('underscore.string/slugify')`.

You don't need to include the path to the js file. If you select the directory, then `node.js` try to find `index.js` file.